# Celery not picking CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER settings

Tags: python, django, celery

I am running Django 1.8 + Celery 4.0.2
Celery is configured well and can run my Django tasks locally on redis backend.
But when I try to use `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` settings,
this settings has no effect. Which is not the case with other settings, e.g. `CELERY_TIMEZONE`

Specifically, in `pdb` I see that `app.conf.task_always_eager` is `False`

> lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py(520)apply_async()
>   So somehow CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER is not picked up and has no effect on app.conf.task_always_eager

More info from pdb:

```
> app.conf.get('CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER')
> True
> app.conf.task_always_eager
> False
```

What can cause this? I know that Celery 4.x is in transition from old setting names to new ones, but they still promise old settings names still would be used as well.

Comment: have you placed `from .celery import app as celery_app` in your `proj/proj/__init__.py`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` has been renamed to `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER` in version 4.0+.

More accurately, all-caps settings have been deprecated in favor of directly configuring the celery app object, and several have been namespaced to either use `task_` or `worker_` as a prefix.  Because there's still backwards-compatability with all-caps settings, this indirectly renamed the all-caps setting as well.

From the [changelog](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.0/whatsnew-4.0.html#lowercase-setting-names):

> The celery_ prefix has also been removed, and task related settings from this name-space is now prefixed by task_, worker related settings with worker_.

Answer (score -1):

Please restart celery worker after setting CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True in settings.py and see if it helps.

Comment: I am event not running a worker, I have Django runserver running (also, restarted) and expecting celery tasks to execute inside it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your point. How you are managing celery to up and running? are you managing it through supervisor? Did you run this command **celery worker -A yourapp --loglevel=INFO** to start celery or something else

Comment: I managed to run celery worker -A yourapp --loglevel=INFO successfully and it's receieving tasks.
Now I have a different goal: to help other developers run Django and tasks without celery, so that tasks are immediately executed inside Django process. For instance, this helps debugging tasks.

Comment: Can confirm with CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True in settings will run the tasks synchronously (so in multi-setting environments changing testing and local environments) one doesn't need to start up celery.

This is helpful for team members who don't know celery and reduces overhead.